# When is onTransition codes executed, exactly? -- Akka, FSM

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I have a doubt whether the code in the "onTransition" block (akka FSM) is executed *after* the new state is reached? or *before* the new state is reached.

The articles and book I've read mentions the word "during"... which (to me) suggests "before the new state is reached".

Does it really matter?

I guess so... I mean, changing to a new state implies (in most cases) changing the state data. Usually we would change that state data in the event handler (in the "when-case-event" block).

But what if the new state depends on the outcome of calculations / actions performed in the "onTransition" block? In that case, we will have to move that block into the "when-case-event" block.

So, it's not clear for me now...: is there any rule / guidance: what actions should go into the "when-case-event", and what actions should go into the "onTransition"?

> > addition: I hope in the next revision of Akka Doc, some kind of clarification / guidance on this topic would be included.

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onTransition` the old state data is available via `stateData`, and the new state data is available as `nextStateData`. The new state cannot be changed by `onTransition`, but you can send a message to `self`.

Comment: Which state gets the message to `self`? Old or new?